# API to translate group name to group id (gid)

Tags: ruby, linux, unix

`File.chown` takes an owner ID, a group ID (gid), and a filename.  I want to use it to set a file's gid, but what I have is the group *name*.  Is there anything in the standard library that I can use to translate a group name into a gid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with ruby, but the Linux syscall for this is `struct group* getgrnam(const char* name)` And is obtained from the `/etc/group` file.

According to [this site](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/etc/rdoc/index.html) you can find this functionality in the `Etc` module:

```
Etc.getgrnam(‘users’) -> 
    #<struct Struct::Group
             name="users",
             passwd="x",
             gid=100,
             mem=["meta", "root"]>
```